# How to count string data in array 2 dimension and show in table with angular

Tags: html, arrays, json, angular

I have data like this below , I want to count that status and How should I count it and show on my table in HTML.

ps: I'm using Angular 8
ps2: Help me pls I stuck with this so long.

```
 0: Array(2)
    0: {uId: "5920502142", name: "นายสุกฤษฏิ์ ทับซ้อน", date: "11/07/2020 00:17", time: "00:17", status: "ONTIME"}
    1: {uId: "5920502142", name: "นายสุกฤษฏิ์ ทับซ้อน", date: "11/07/2020 00:29", time: "-", status: "ABSENT"}
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array(0)
    1: Array(2)
    0: {uId: "6020500357", name: "นายเกียรติพันธ์ พิทักษ์วงศ์", date: "11/07/2020 00:17", time: "00:25", status: "ONTIME"}
    1: {uId: "6020500357", name: "นายเกียรติพันธ์ พิทักษ์วงศ์", date: "11/07/2020 00:29", time: "-", status: "ABSENT"}
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array(0)
    2: Array(2)
    0: {uId: "6020500365", name: "นายธนาธร ทรงพินิจ", date: "11/07/2020 00:17", time: "00:26", status: "LATE"}
    1: {uId: "6020500365", name: "นายธนาธร ทรงพินิจ", date: "11/07/2020 00:29", time: "-", status: "ABSENT"}
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array(0)
    3: Array(2)
    0: {uId: "6020500373", name: "นายใบชา เจนจบวิทยา", date: "11/07/2020 00:17", time: "-", status: "ABSENT"}
    1: {uId: "6020500373", name: "นายใบชา เจนจบวิทยา", date: "11/07/2020 00:29", time: "-", status: "ABSENT"}
    length: 2
    __proto__: Array(0)
    4: Array(2)
    0: {uId: "6020500381", name: "นายภาณุภัสส์ ธนัชญ์สุธาโชติ", date: "11/07/2020 00:17", time: "-", status: "ABSENT"}
    1: {uId: "6020500381", name: "นายภาณุภัสส์ ธนัชญ์สุธาโชติ", date: "11/07/2020 00:29", time: "-", status: "ABSENT"}
    length: 2
```

Comment: what are you looking for?, something like `{status: string, count: number}`?

Comment: yeah something like that I need to count status to display on HTML

Comment: And I have 3 status "ONTIME","LATE","ABSENT"

Answer (score 0):

A full count of status, could be done using `reduce` method like this,

```
data = [
  [
    { uId: "5920502142", name: "นายสุกฤษฏิ์ ทับซ้อน", date: "11/07/2020 00:17", time: "00:17", status: "ONTIME" }
    , { uId: "5920502142", name: "นายสุกฤษฏิ์ ทับซ้อน", date: "11/07/2020 00:29", time: "-", status: "ABSENT" }
  ],
  [
    { uId: "6020500357", name: "นายเกียรติพันธ์ พิทักษ์วงศ์", date: "11/07/2020 00:17", time: "00:25", status: "ONTIME" }
    , { uId: "6020500357", name: "นายเกียรติพันธ์ พิทักษ์วงศ์", date: "11/07/2020 00:29", time: "-", status: "ABSENT" }
  ],
  [
    { uId: "6020500365", name: "นายธนาธร ทรงพินิจ", date: "11/07/2020 00:17", time: "00:26", status: "LATE" }
    , { uId: "6020500365", name: "นายธนาธร ทรงพินิจ", date: "11/07/2020 00:29", time: "-", status: "ABSENT" }
  ],
  [
    { uId: "6020500373", name: "นายใบชา เจนจบวิทยา", date: "11/07/2020 00:17", time: "-", status: "ABSENT" }
    , { uId: "6020500373", name: "นายใบชา เจนจบวิทยา", date: "11/07/2020 00:29", time: "-", status: "ABSENT" }
  ],
  [
    { uId: "6020500381", name: "นายภาณุภัสส์ ธนัชญ์สุธาโชติ", date: "11/07/2020 00:17", time: "-", status: "ABSENT" }
    , { uId: "6020500381", name: "นายภาณุภัสส์ ธนัชญ์สุธาโชติ", date: "11/07/2020 00:29", time: "-", status: "ABSENT" }

  ]
]

const reducer = (accumulator, arr1) => {
  for (const arr2 of arr1) accumulator[arr2.status]++;
  return accumulator;
};
const statusCount = data.reduce(
  reducer,
  { ONTIME: 0, LATE: 0, ABSENT: 0 }
);

console.log(statusCount);
```

output

```
{ ONTIME: 2, LATE: 1, ABSENT: 7 }
```

BTW, I am assuming that status always take those three values.

Answer (score 0):

You could also [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/flat) the data set and make the [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) a bit simpler.

```
let flat = data.flat();

const count = flat.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item.status]++;
  return acc;
},
{
    ONTIME: 0,
    LATE: 0,
    ABSENT: 0
});

console.log(count);
```